# SQL Server query runs slower when nothing is returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query runs slowly when the result set is empty. When there is something to return, it is lightning fast.

```
    ;with tree(NodeId,CategoryId,ParentId) as (
        select ct.NodeId, ct.CategoryId, ct.ParentId
        from dbo.CategoryTree as ct
        where ct.ParentId = 6
        union all
        select t.NodeId, t.CategoryId, t.ParentId from dbo.CategoryTree as t
        inner join tree as t2 on t.ParentId = t2.NodeId
    ), branch(NodeId,CategoryId,ParentId) as
    (
        select NodeId, CategoryId, ParentId from dbo.CategoryTree as t
        where t.NodeId = 6
        union all
        select NodeId, CategoryId, ParentId
        from tree as t
    ),facil(FacilityId) as(
        select distinct fct.FacilityId
        from dbo.FacilitiesCategoryTree as fct
        inner join branch b on b.NodeId = fct.CategoryNodeId
    )

    select top 51 f.Id, f.CityId, f.NameGEO,
     f.NameENG, f.NameRUS, f.DescrGEO, f.DescrENG,
     f.DescrRUS, f.MoneyMin, f.MoneyAvg, f.Lat, f.Lng, f.SortIndex,
     f.FrontImgUrl from dbo.Facilities f
     inner join facil t2 on t2.FacilityId = f.Id
        and f.EnabledUntil > 'Jan 14 2015 10:23PM'
     order by f.SortIndex
```

Principal tables are:
Facilities table holds facilities, 256k records.
CategoryTree is used to group categories in a hierarchy.

```
NodeId int,
CategoryId int,
ParentId int
```

FacilitiesCategoryTree is used to link CategoryTree to Facilities.

Given NodeId, the second CTE returns all the nodes that are descendant of the given node including itself. Then there is a third CTE that returns facility ids that belong to these nodes.

Finally, the last CTE is joined to actual facilities table. The result is ordered by SortIndex which is used to manually indicate the order of facilities.

This query runs very fast when there is something to return even if I include many more predicates including full-text search and others, but when the given branch does not have any facilities, this query takes approx. 2 seconds to run.

If I exclude the order by clause, the query runs very fast again. All these tables are indexed and the query optimizer does not suggest any improvements.

What do you think is the problem and what can be done to improve the performance of queries with empty results?

Thank you.

**Update1:
I am adding execution plans.**

http://www.filedropper.com/withorderby

http://www.filedropper.com/withoutorderby

**Update2:**
I went through the recommendations of oryol and tried to save facility IDs from tree to the table variable and join it with facilities table and order by SortIndex. It eliminated the problem with empty results, but increased the execution time of queries with a result set from 250ms to 950ms.

I also changed the query to select from facil and join to the Facilities and added option (force order). The result was the same as above.

Finally, I denormalized facility/category mapping table to include SortIndex in this table. It increased the execution time of normal queries slightly from 250ms to 300ms, but it resolved the empty result set problem. I guess, I’ll stick to this method.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` must have given a wrong hint to the query optimizer, like using an inefficient index. Can you post the execution plans with and without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I have added both execution plans in the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing - you can slightly simplify the first two CTEs to just one:

```
with tree(NodeId,CategoryId,ParentId) as (
        select ct.NodeId, ct.CategoryId, ct.ParentId
        from dbo.CategoryTree as ct
        where ct.NodeId = 6
        union all
        select t.NodeId, t.CategoryId, t.ParentId from dbo.CategoryTree as t
        inner join tree as t2 on t.ParentId = t2.NodeId
    )
```

The main problem that optimizer don't know or incorrectly estimate number of facilities which will be returned for your categories. And because you need facilities ordered by `SortIndex` optimizer decides to:

- Go through all facilities ordered by `SortIndex` (using the appropriate index)
- Skip rows which are not covered by other filters (`EnabledUntil`)
- Using given `Facility Id` find one row in facilities from categories tree. If it exists returns result row. If not - skip this facility.
- Repeat these iteration until 51 rows will be returned

So, in the worst case (if there are no 51 such facilities or they have very big `SortIndex`) it will require scan of all `idx_Facilities_SortIndex` and it requires a lot of time.

There are several ways to resolve this issue (including hints to optimizer to tell about row count or join order) to find the best way it's better to work with real database. First option which can be tried is to change query to:

- Save facility IDs from tree to the table variable
- Join it with facilities table and order by SortIndex

Another option (can be also comined with the first one) is to try to use `FORCE ORDER` query hint. In such case you will need to modify your select statement to select from `facil` and join it to the `Facilities` and add `option (force order)` query hint to the end of statement.

Query without order by select all facilities from tree. And after that extract other facility fields from facilities table.

Also, it's important to know about actual size of facilities in the tree (according to the estimates in the execution plan without order by it's really big - 395982). Does this estimate (more or less) correct?

If you really have a big amount of facilities returned after joining with category tree and facility/categories mapping table then the best solution will be to denormalize facility/category mapping table to include SortIndex in this table and add index to this table by `NodeId` and `SortIndex`.

So actually, we need to test queries / indexes with real data. Or to know different statistics of data:

- Categories amount
- Number of facilities per category and total number of rows in facilities / categories mapping table
- SortIndex distribution (is it unique?)
- etc.